# Timeout for nfs

Tags: linux, tcp, nfs

I have mounted nfs using **proto=tcp** **timeo=30** **retrans=1** **retry=0**

It mounts immidiately and then I start writing data to it. Now when I disconnect the nfs server from network,client hungs on write, prints

**server not responding, timed out**

for 9 times and then returns from write with **I/O Error** and continues further process.

I need to reduce the time Write taking to return the Error, I tried using reducing timeo and checked other options of nfs mount but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `soft`/`hard` can help. Or `bg`/`fg`.

I don't know it'll help or not, but manual suggest it can.

Check also https://serverfault.com/a/231478

Comment: I had already tried with soft/hard,it didnt worked,will give a try to fg/bg